# How to Export HTML to PDF Using Telerik with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, server-side, telerik-reporting

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC application where emails are sent to users with HTML content (Multiple tables) in the body.

Now I have to export and download same data as a PDF file in the browser.  Since I have the HTML content already generated, my plan is to convert this HTML to PDF by using Telerik (Since i have license) in my MVC controller.

If HTML to PDF conversion is not possible, please let me know how can i create a PDF with multiple tables using Telerik DLLs as I've never used Telerik controls.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Did you get answer for this?

Comment: Hi, I could not find any solution for exporting HTML to PDF.  Instead I've created a PDF from scratch using Telerik controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I fixed it by generating a PDF from scratch using telerik controls.**

Answer (score 0):

If the data you send is in a Telerik grid you can simple try to do this:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/pdf-export

On the otherhand you can also try to use aspose: https://www.aspose.com/products/pdf/net

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Actually, data is html table but not from telerik grid.  I fixed it by generating a PDF from scratch using telerik controls.